# Animate UIView from UIButton

Tags: ios, animation

I want to bring options view from the settings button. Options view will have only 2 buttons with icons.  It should look like a strip.

Can anyone help me in this...

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Have you even google'd this question? Google 'animate UIView' and you will see a lot of information.

In case you want specific information, get us some source-code so we could look into a specific problem.

Comment: If you can get, can you please provide me the google search link for this question?

Comment: No, but in any case, thanks for down voting for no reason. Still if you are looking for an answer — 

> create: a UIView with two buttons
> add it as a subview using animations.

For either of those things, google it.